# Codeigniter custom form_validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a added custom function to the system->libraries->Form_validation.php

---

```
public function serial_exist($str, $value)
{

    list($table, $column) = explode('.', $value, 2);
    $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $table WHERE $column = '$str'");
    $row = $query->row();

    if ($row->count > 0) {
        $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM v_redeem WHERE v_serial='$str'");
        $row = $query->row();
        if ($row->count > 0) {
            /// used
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    } else {
        //invalid serial
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The I call the function from the below.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('serial','serial','required|xss_clean|serial_exist[v_info.v_serial]');
```

This works just fine but my issue how can I get the to different MSG say'n either invalid or used serial?

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a custom set_message.
like this---

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('serial_exist', 'Your custom Message.');
```

Comment: On my function it 1st check if the value is present in one table and check if it is not present on another table. I need to receive error MSG when these statues are checked.